# MySQL Date_Format return "i" in Excel

Tags: mysql, excel

I'm trying to make a simply batch that will run a query and generate a .xls file with selected data.

The issue is that in my query i use `DATE_FORMAT(ORAIN_PTV, '%H:%i') AS ORA` which in MySQL return the correct value of "HH:mm" / ex: "13:30" while when the data is exported in excel it look like a simple "i" char.

[image]

How can i fix that issue?

here is what my batch file looks like:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin 
mysql -u root -pxxx -e "SELECT DESCLI_PTV AS NOME, DATAIN_PTV AS DATA, DATE_FORMAT(ORAIN_PTV, '%H:%i') AS ORA, NUMCOP_PTV AS COPERTI, TELCLI_PTV AS TELEFONO, EMACLI_PTV AS EMAIL FROM myristo.prenota_tavoli WHERE DATAIN_PTV = CURDATE();" > C:\Users\imytyuk\Desktop\PRENOTAZIONI.xls
```